# Windows bat: How to loop files in sub directories

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to use a bat named `process.bat` to process all of jpg files in some sub directories.

```
dir
 |---subdir1
 |     |-----a.jpg
 |     |-----b.jpg
 |
 |---subdir2
       |-----c.jpg
       |-----d.jpg

process.bat dir/subdir1/a.jpg dir/subdir1/b.jpg
process.bat dir/subdir2/c.jpg dir/subdir2/d.jpg
```

In Linux, I can make such a script:

```
find $1 -type d | while read dir; do
    files=("$dir"/*.jpg)
    if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
        if ! [[ $files =~ \* ]]; then
            process.bat "${files[@]}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing in Windows.
I've known how to loop files in Windows bat: `for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir` should be an absolut path:

```
> tree . /F
C:\TEST\DIR
├───subdir1
│       a.jpg
│       b.jpg
│
├───subdir2
│       c.jpg
│       d.jpg
│
└───subdir3
```

---

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /d %%A in (C:\Test\dir\*) Do (
  Set "Files="
  For %%B in ("%%~fA\*.jpg") Do Set Files=!Files! "%%~fB"
  If defined Files echo process.bat !Files!
)
```

Sample output with echo :

```
process.bat  "C:\Test\dir\subdir1\a.jpg" "C:\Test\dir\subdir1\b.jpg"
process.bat  "C:\Test\dir\subdir2\c.jpg" "C:\Test\dir\subdir2\d.jpg"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402963/windows-bat-loop-files-in-directories

Comment: Read my answer in this link. Reedit a little bit your answer may be more helpful for others.