# Windows bat: loop files in directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I'm working on Windows. I have many `jpg` files in subdirectories of a directory. I don't know exactly the architecture of the directory, meaning that I don't know how many levels the subdirectories have. What I need to do is to process `jpg` files according to their paths. Here is an example:

```
dir
 |---sub dir1
 |      |-----sub dir11
 |               |-----a.jpg
 |               |-----b.jpg
 |---sub dir2
        |-----c.jpg
        |-----d.jpg
```

So I need to execute commands as below:

```
process.bat C:\dir\sub dir1\sub dir11\a.jpg C:\dir\sub dir1\sub dir11\b.jpg
process.bat C:\dir\sub dir2\c.jpg C:\dir\sub dir2\d.jpg
```

I don't know how to write such a bat file especially a bat processing paths contains spaces. I don't know if spaces will make some trouble.

I've tried as below but it doesn't work:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

For /d %%A in (C:\dir\*) Do (
    Set "Files="
    For /f %%B in ("%%~fA\*.jpg") Do Set Files=!Files! "%%~fB"
    If defined Files echo process.bat %%~fA\*.jpg
)

pause
```

When I execute the script, I get the result as below:

```
process.bat C:\dir\sub dir1\*.jpg
process.bat C:\dir\sub dir2\*.jpg
```

It seems that `*` is regarded as a normal character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

For /d %%A in (C:\dir\*) Do (
    Set "Files="
    For /F "delims=" %%B in ('dir /S /B "%%~fA\*.jpg"') Do Set Files=!Files! "%%~fB"
    If defined Files echo process.bat !Files!
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If defined Files echo process.bat !files!
```

should solve the problem - but whether `process.bat` will co-operate is yet to be determined. Would need you to list `process.bat` if required.

Comment: I just try your change. It seems to work except that the spaces in the paths invoke another problem. Now I get such a result: `process.bat C:\dir\sub  process.bat C:\dir\sub`

Comment: I just remove all of spaces in the paths and it still doesn't work. I got this:`process.bat C:\dir\subdir1\*.jpg process.bat C:\dir\subdir2\*.jpg`