# Windows bat: how to process files for each subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to use a bat named `here.bat` to process files in the same directories. Here is an example:

```
mydir
 |----mybat.bat
 |----here.bat
 |----subdir
        |-----subdir2
                 |-----subdir3
                          |-----subdir31
                          |        |-----a.jpg
                          |
                          |-----subdir32
                                   |-----b.jpg
```

I need to use `here.bat` to process `a.jpg` and `b.jpg`. So I write a bat file named `mybat.bat` as below:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

For /d %%A in (.\subdir\*) Do (
  Set "Files="
  For /F "delims=" %%B in ('dir /S /B "%%~fA\*.jpg"') Do Set Files=!Files! "%%~fB"
  If defined Files echo call here.bat !Files!
)

pause
```

When I execute `mybat.bat`, I get the result as below:

```
call here.bat "C:\Users\me\mydir\subdir\subdir2\subdir3\subdire31\a.jpg" "C:\Users\me\mydir\subdir\subdir2\subdir3\sudbir32\b.jpg"
```

But this is not what I need. I need to process `jpg` files which are in the same directory with `here.bat`, if they are not in the same directory, they should be processed separately. Meaning that I need the result as below:

```
call here.bat "C:\Users\me\mydir\subdir\subdir2\subdir3\subdire31\a.jpg"
call here.bat "C:\Users\me\mydir\subdir\subdir2\subdir3\sudbir32\b.jpg"
```

Comment: Why is the answer in [your other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402963/windows-bat-loop-files-in-directories) not adequate?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  In my opinion, it is because the sub paths in the other question are totally different:`subdir1...` and `subdir2...`. But here the sub paths are quite similar. Well, I'm not sure... But you can try my answer in that question. I believe that you will get the same problem.

Comment: But the same techniques should work, differing only in the details. You may need to take some time to learn more about programming in general, and batch programming specifically, so that you can solve these problems yourself, instead of repeatedly asking questions that really have only minor differences in conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your changing requirements make it difficult to provide a solution in the first run. This version should do:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R ".\subdir" %%A in (.) do (
  Set "Files="
  If Exist "%%~fA\*.jpg" For /F "delims=" %%B in (
      'dir /B "%%~fA\*.jpg"') Do Set Files=!Files! "%%~fB"
  If defined Files echo call here.bat !Files!
)
pause
```